# ruby / rails boolean method naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, naming-conventions

I have a short question on ruby / rails method naming conventions or good practice.
Consider the following methods:

```
# some methods performing some sort of 'action'
def action; end
def action!; end

# some methods checking if performing 'action' is permitted
def action?; end
def can_action?; end
def action_allowed?; end
```

So I wonder, which of the three ampersand-methods would be the "best" way to ask for permissions. I would go with the first one somehow, but in some cases I think this might be confused with meaning `has_performed_action?`.
So the second approach might make that clearer but is also a bit more verbose. The third one is actually just for completeness. I don't really like that one.

So are there any commonly agreed-on good practices for that?

Comment: I think the best option is when the code is most readable. In my opinion the 3rd form looks better. Specially because I can read "if action_allowed?". or a slightly better option (again in my opinion) would be action_is_allowed?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that depends on the action you want to perform and the action you are checking for. I would aim for readability and least amount of confusion:

```
self.run
self.can_run? # can this object run?
self.running_allowed? # is running allowed here or by this user?

self.redeem!
self.redeemable? # is this object currently redeemable?

self.copy_to_clipboard
self.copy_to_dashboard
self.copyable? or self.can_be_copied? #can this object be copied
self.copy_allowed?(:clipboard) # is copying to the clipboard allowed by me?
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `action?`, because typically, single-word question-mark methods are used to indicate the presence (or absence) of a value. Rails lets you write English-like code, so pick a method name that makes the code the most readable.

```
perform_action!("update") if action_allowed?("update")
```

Seems perfectly readable to me.

Comment: Hmm, that `action?` remark seems to make sense. However, what I am a bit worried about is the whole lot of different ways you might use to ask for allowance. Which might be `action_allowed?`, `action_permitted?`, `action_authorized?`, `action_granted?`. I think in bigger teams this might become an issue, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go up one level and rethink the original method names.  If the methods perform an action, then the role they play is that of a verb, not a noun:

```
# some methods performing some sort of 'action'
def act
def act!
```

This has the handy side effect of a more natural-sounding answer to your question:

```
# method checking if 'action' is permitted
def can_act?
```

...as well as some other obvious variants:

```
# methods checking if 'action' was performed
def acted?
def did_act?

# method checking if 'action' is called for by other circumstances
def should_act?

# method putting 'action' into a work queue
def act_later(delay_seconds=0)
```

Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

```
def can_action?; end
```